# How to create segmented buttons in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

How to achieve the following appearance of buttons in macOS swiftui?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use a `Picker` with a `SegmentedPickerStyle`:

```
Picker(selection: $selectedOption, label: Text(""), content: {
    Text("+")
    Text("-")
}).pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
```

`$selectedOption` is a binding:

`@State var selectedOption: Int?`

Comment: What is the equivalent of `Button`'s `action` here?

Comment: `.onChange(of: selectedOption) { ... }` probably, @RobN

Comment: Two problems with this: 1. If you click a "+" button twice, it should run its action twice. But this only runs the action if you click the button differently than last time (ie, the value changes). 2. The button appears selected, and that changes from one to the other as you click them.

Comment: You can set the selected option back to nil when you're done running the action. macOS pickers can have empty selections.